# Passing values between Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

In `FragmentPageradapter`  I have 3 fragments. In first two fragments there is a `SeekBar`. When either of the `SeekBar` changes its value in `fragment1`, I want to change the value of`SeekBar` which is inside `fragment2`. How can I achieve It?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution as follows :

1. First create an interface

   ```
   public interface SeekChangeInterface {
       public void sendChangedValue(int value)
   }
   ```
2. Implement it your Activity where the `FragmentPagerAdapter` Belongs
3. Create a object of interface in first fragment

   ```
   SeekChangeInterface  mSeekChangeInterface;
   ```
4. Declare `onAttach()` in the first fragment

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

       mSeekChangeInterface = (SeekChangeInterface )activity;
   }
   ```
5. In seekbar change lisener call

   ```
   mSeekChangeInterface.sendChangedValue(valueofseekbar)
   ```
6. Create a method in second fragment

   ```
   public void setSeekBarValue(int progress){
       seekBar.setProgress(progress);
   }
   ```
7. Call this method from the Activity `sendChangedValue()`

   ```
    public void sendChangedValue(int progress){
        objectoffragnentpageradapter.getItem(1).setSeekBarValue(progress);
    }
   ```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Do not hold a reference to the fragment and try to update it this way. The fragment may be null, or not attached yet.

Try to use the Activity. Implement an setter in your activity and use it in the seekbar change listener to set the current value.
In the other fragment use the activity to restore the value.

Something like:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).setSeekValue(40);
((MyActivity) getActivity()).getSeekValue();
```

note that this is not a perfect solution as the activity can be null too (add null checks) and you have to cast to MyActivity. But i think it is a usable quick solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: But how can i notify this value in another fragment in Fragment pager adapter ? onresume is not called when the tabviewpager changes

Comment: see comment in Mahmoud Elmorabea's answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is have your activity be responsible for the communication, meaning that when the seekbar changes, the fragment should do something like this:

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).notifySeekBarValueChanged(int);
```

And in your activity

```
private void notifySeekBarValueChanged(int value) {
    MyFragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(int);
    frag.seekBarValueChangedTo(value);
}
```

Another way to go is to use some sort of messaging mechanism between your fragments like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: Maybe a combination of both would be usefull. if fragment gets created by the adapter the value can be restored in onResume via the activity. if the fragment already exists the eventbus propagates the new value.

Comment: There is a way with EventBus to have a default value if exists when you register for the first time, but great suggestion :)

Comment: I was not aware of this feature of EventBus :)